# Problem with headers seemingly not working in c++ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, header

I am currently using Visual Studio Code to learn c++ using the book "accelerated c++", on chapter 4. It involves a program containing several functions and works fine as long es everything is in one .cpp file.
After seperating the functions into three .cpp files with corresponding headers (all in the same folder) and trying to "run c/c++ file" through the button in the top right, it gives the error "'...\program.exe' does not exist" (with the option to open 'launch.json') and says "undefined reference to '...'.
The undefined reference error is always the first function from a header the main program would have to use.

I tried the same thing with a simple "Hello world!" program where it works fine if everything is in one .cpp file but gives the same error "run c/c++ file". Following code:

main program (greet.cpp):

```
#include<iostream>
#include"hello.h"

using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;

int main()
{
    cout << hello(cin) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

header (hello.h):

```
#ifndef GUARD_hello_h
#define GUARD_hello_h

#include<string>
#include<iostream>

std::string hello(std::istream&);

#endif
```

hello function (hello.cpp):

```
#include"hello.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::istream; using std::string; using std::cout; using std::endl;

string hello(istream& in)
{
    cout << endl << "Please enter your name:   ";
    string name;
    in >> name;
    cout << endl;
    string hi = "Hello " + name + "!";
    return hi;
}
```

The "Hello world!" does work when using the cmd terminal and typing g++ -o greet.exe greet.cpp hello.cpp, this does not work for my main problem and also doesn't seem like it should be the solution.

Comment: How has VSCode been configured? How are you building from VSCode? With what plugin (there are apparently a couple of different plugins that can be used)? Are both of the source files *and* the header file in the same directory? And please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build log into it.

Comment: As an educated ***guess***, you haven't written a `tasks.json` file for building, or it's misconfigured, so only the current source file you're editing is being built. Please read [the VSCode documentstion](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs) for more details.

Comment: And lastly some nitpicking: The error you're getting have nothing to do with header files. Any decent book or tutorial should have taught you that building a C++ application is done in three steps: 1) Edit source and header files; 2) Build source files, which then includes the header files, this step creates *object files*; And 3) Link the object files into the final executable program. Your error comes in step 3, which can happen long after the compilation and header file inclusion.

Comment: If you have more than 1 source file remember that VSCode only builds the active file by default. This part of the documentation tells you that and how to change it to build all source files in your folder: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: You've made the mistake that it seems every single newbie programmer does when they use VSCode to compile more than one cpp file. MS really should improve their documentation.

Comment: @john I think the bigger problem is that few newbies actually read the documentation, or maybe doesn't even know it exists. The actual documentation, once read, is actually rather good.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in multiple comments, the answer was to just replace the `${file}` in the tasks.json file with `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"` to compile all .cpp files, not just the active one. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the intelliSenseMode in the c_cpp_properties.json. Change it to "linux-clang-x64"